# JSON value could be null

Tags: c#, json

So... I got the "Parse" class from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33176697/read-json-when-array-represented-as-objects-with-itemxxx-properties) and it works fine, if all the values are returned correctly from the JSON string but, if in my case, some JSON value aren't available (they simply doesn't exist, "items" and "current_time" doesn't exist.) the programm, of course, crash.

My question is, how I can counter that ? I already tried to store the JSON values into variables but this also make the programm crash, without more infos given.

Work :

```
{
    "response": {
        "success": 1,
        "current_time": 1445015502,
        "items": {
            "item1": {
                "property1": 1,
                "property2": "test",
                "property3": 4.3
            },
            "item2": {
                "property1": 5,
                "property2": "test2",
                "property3": 7.8
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Crash :

```
{
    "response": {
        "success": 0,
        "message": "not available",
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show all of the code your are trying? It's not clear what is going on here just by having the JSON data to view.

Comment: @Krythic Isn't that a song?? :)

Comment: Jason Evans, well, not sure if I need to edit my OP, but the link with all the code I have is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33176697/read-json-when-array-represented-as-objects-with-itemxxx-properties - Mati Cicero answer.

Comment: seems like these are responses to some AJAX calls or smth of the sort. You need to handle success and failure differently. You know what to expect in both situations, so you handle it appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is going to be in here:

```
private RootObject Parse(string jsonString)
{
   dynamic jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
   RootObject parsed = new RootObject()
   {
        response = new Response()
        {
              success = jsonObject.response.success,
              current_time = jsonObject.response.current_time,
              message = jsonObject.response.message,
              items = ParseItems(jsonObject.response.items)
        }  
   };
   return parsed;
}
```

Before you parse the object, you need to determine if it is a valid (successful)  object, so you need to do something like this:

```
private RootObject Parse(string jsonString)
{
   dynamic jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
   if (jsonObject.response.success == 0)
   {
      //The response object is not valid and has a message...
      throw new InvalidArgumentException("I don't know what to do");
   }
   else
   {
      RootObject parsed = new RootObject()
      {
           response = new Response()
           {
              success = jsonObject.response.success,
              current_time = jsonObject.response.current_time,
              message = jsonObject.response.message,
              items = ParseItems(jsonObject.response.items)
           }  
      };
      return parsed;
   }
}
```

Or you could do:

```
private RootObject Parse(string jsonString)
{
   dynamic jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
   RootObject parsed = null;
   if (jsonObject.response.success == 0)
   {
      //The response object is not valid and has a message...
      parsed = new RootObject()
      {
           response = new Response()
           {
              success = jsonObject.response.success,
              message = jsonObject.response.message
           } 
      };
   }
   else
   {
      parsed = new RootObject()
      {
           response = new Response()
           {
              success = jsonObject.response.success,
              current_time = jsonObject.response.current_time,
              message = jsonObject.response.message,
              items = ParseItems(jsonObject.response.items)
           }  
      };
   }
   return parsed;
}
```

Comment: It may also be worth noting that in your example, the successful data set does not have a "message" property, don't know where the error is though so I'll leave that up to you to remove it or keep it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to validate if the "items" field is null before using it.

If you already did this, I think we will need more info.